# How can I extract the First Word in a Cell when the words are separated by a comma?

Tags: google-sheets

So let's say this is column C.

Coker, Jared
Palmer, Drew
Bryant, Will

I want to pull just the first word from these cells to another cell in say column O.

How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a pattern-match feature called ["regular expression matching"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244):

> =REGEXEXTRACT(C1, "[^,]*")

This means: Extract a sequence of not-comma characters.

Another possibility is to use the [SPLIT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) function, but it stores each of the split-out substrings (e.g. "Coker" and "Jared") in separate cells. If the string has more commas, `SPLIT()` will store into more cells.

Another possibility is to use [SEARCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154) or [FIND()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126) to find the first `,`, combined with [LEFT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079) to extract the left part of the string:

> =LEFT(C1, FIND(",", C1) - 1)

but this will produce a `#VALUE!` error if the string doesn't contain a `,`.

Comment: Very nice, @pnuts! This feature is not documented in the reference page for `INDEX()`, https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242

Answer (score 0):

You can use char code as well, the below is example with space

```
=LEFT(A59, FIND(CHAR(160), A59) - 1)
```